# How many "Inner Mongolian political refugees" might be in Mongolia?

Tags: china, asylum, mongolia

France24 says in relation with the arrest of a Mongolian opposition figure (who was critical of Mongolia's close[r] relations with China) [that](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20220222-prominent-anti-china-activist-arrested-in-mongolia)

> Activists also say China has pressured Mongolia to deport Inner Mongolian political refugees back to the country.

(Inner Mongolia is a region of China, if that needs clarification.)

So, roughly how many of these "Inner Mongolian political refugees" might be in Mongolia?

Comment: I suspect the official number is zero, and the piece is talking about some kind of unofficial refuge, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: How many unofficial refugees are there then?

Comment: @alamar: yeah, is there some kind of estimate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Chinese Migrants In Mongolia**

Wikipedia can provide at least [an order of magnitude upper bound estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_Chinese_in_Mongolia) of this number although it does not break out refugees separately, and refugees could have different immigration statuses:

> Chinese Mongolians can be subdivided into three groups: Mongolian
> citizens of ethnic Chinese background, temporary residents with
> Chinese citizenship, and permanent residents with Chinese citizenship.
> Mongolia's 1956 census counted ethnic Chinese as 1.9% of the
> population; the United States government estimated their proportion to
> be 2% in 1987, or roughly 40,000 people. The 2000 census showed 1,323
> permanent residents of Chinese descent; this figure does not include
> naturalised citizens, temporary residents, nor illegal immigrants.
> Illegal immigrants from China were estimated at 10,000 in the 1990s;
> some use Mongolia as a transit point into Russia.

**The Number Of People Mongolia Admits Are Refugees**

The official number of refugees in Mongolia according to the Mongolian government is minimal and mostly North Korean:

[One source](https://www.ohchr.org/sites/default/files/lib-docs/HRBodies/UPR/Documents/session9/MN/HRCC_HumanRightsCenterforCitizens.pdf) states that:

> As of June 2008, an estimated 38,0008 foreign citizens including
> stateless persons reside in Mongolia.
>
> 30. The spokesman of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs informed us, that as of October 2009, there are no refugees registered to have entered
>     Mongolia.  However, while we were preparing this report, the UN
>     officer in charge of refugee issues informed us that the government
>     had deported an asylum seeker who had applied for assistance and
>     protection of his rights.
> 31. There is also information that another citizen from China’s Inner Mongolian region was deported in 2009. Reportedly, this person was
>     repatriated when the UNDP Refugee Agency was reviewing his
>     application, dully filed by him and in accordance with the procedures.
>     We were informed that this act is considered to be in serious
>     violation of international practices and human rights conventions,
>     including CAT.
> 32. Mongolia is not party to international conventions dealing with the rights of refugees. The reason for the reluctance is explained by
>     the National Security Council not having delivered an opinion on its
>     impact. Cabinet used the absence of NSC opinion to not to discuss and
>     deliver decision on this submission.
> 33. There is informal unconfirmed information that North Korean citizens seeking asylum enter Mongolia via China. Government lacking
>     financial resources leaves these matters to be handled by
>     international organizations. Due to secrecy surrounding this issue and
>     lack of information human rights organizations have no material to
>     work with. Therefore, one of the priorities of the government of
>     Mongolia should be to provide opportunity to human rights watchers to
>     work with refugees by giving access to information and making the
>     process of granting asylum transparent.

A [2015 report](https://borgenproject.org/refugees-in-mongolia/) claims that there were 9 refugees in Mongolia at the time, mostly from North Korea. [Another source](https://migrants-refugees.va/country-profile/mongolia/), apparently based on official statistics, states that there were only 10 refugees from all places in Mongolia in 2020. [This source](https://www.macrotrends.net/countries/MNG/mongolia/refugee-statistics) claims a range of 5 to 12 refugees at any one time in Mongolia from all sources in the time period from 2006 to 2022.

These are the official numbers of refugees in Mongolia at least.

**Analysis**

The official number of refugees in Mongolia seem doubtful, however. Mongolia's government is probably reluctant to classify anyone from China as a refugee for fear of diplomatic or military consequences from its powerful neighbor, so it classifies them as "illegal immigrants" instead.

The most fair and likely conclusion from easily available data is that the people that the article referenced in the question is referring to as refugees from Inner Mongolia are classified officially by the Mongolian government as illegal immigrants, rather than refugees.

If so, there are probably something on the order of magnitude of 10,000 of them or less migrants from Inner Mongolia in Mongolia who could plausibly be classified by an outsider as a refugees, but there are probably at least several thousand of them.

A [2022 report](https://www.benarnews.org/english/news/thai/man-freed-11032022162954.html) suggests that conditions have worsened in recent years in Inner Mongolia for ethnic Mongolians, however, so there may have been a recent surge in "illegal immigration" from Inner Mongolia to Mongolia.

This estimate of between several thousand and perhaps ten thousand or a bit more, tends to be corroborated by a 2019 news report in which [800 "illegal immigrants" from China](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-mongolia-crime-china/mongolia-arrests-800-chinese-citizens-in-cybercrime-probe-idUSKBN1XA0NW) were arrested and deported from Mongolia back to China, allegedly for participating in cybercrimes. Presumably, this deportations did not include most of the Chinese illegal immigrants in Mongolia at the time, but it was a large enough share of them to be newsworthy.

The same article notes that there are about 160,000 Chinese tourists in Mongolia each year, which would easily facilitate migration from China to Mongolia by people who really want to emigrate as refugees from China, even if their refugee status isn't recognized by Mongolia, in numbers of the right order of magnitude.

**Background**

For reference and context purposes, the total population of [Mongolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia) is about 3.3 million, and the total population of [Inner Mongolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_Mongolia) is about 24 million including about 5 million ethnic Mongolians. China as a whole has a population of about 1.4 billion.